# Install Postrouting in docker postgis-postgresql container

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

I created a postgis database with docker using the postgis image as usual

```
docker run -d \
    --name mypostgres \
    -p 5555:5432 \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
    -v /data/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    -v /data/postgres/lib:/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib \
    postgis/postgis:10-3.0
```

now I can  see all extensiones in the database,it has postgis, it's ok.  but not have postrouting.
so I pull another image:

```
docker pull pgrouting/pgrouting:11-3.1-3.1.3
```

and do the same command:

```
docker run -d \
    --name pgrouting \
    -p 5556:5432 \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
    -v /data/pgrouting/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ \
    -v /data/postgres/lib/:/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/ \
    pgrouting/pgrouting:11-3.1-3.1.3
```

but when I  exec this command:

```
create extensione postrouting
```

I get this error message:

```
could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/plpgsql.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/plpgsql.so: undefined symbol: AllocSetContextCreate
```

I can't solve this problem.Can anyone help me?
thanks a lot

Comment: I can recommend using https://github.com/kartoza/docker-postgis#postgresql-extensions this docker image instead, it has all extensions as options.

Comment: Thanks a lot.   I have try it  and success.     This is the first time I come here to ask questions, thanks to the kind people who answered

Comment: also the command to create the extension should be using `pgrounting`, not `postrouting`